# Testing for Uniform Convergence of the sum of an Alternating Series.

Tags: uniform-convergence

I'm still trying to get used in understanding the concept behind uniform convergence, so there's another questions which I'm currently have trouble trying to answer.

Suppose there's a series $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$ and x is such that $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

My first attempt was to use the Weierstrass' M Test but I can only seem to find $M_k$ such that $$M_k=\frac{1}{2k+1}$$. However, after a comparison test $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}M_k$ doesn't converge.

I tried to find a partial sum of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ to work with similar to the last question I posted such as $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$ where I realise the last term could actually be an even number n=2z or an odd number n=2z+1 and as a result could have an impact on the sign of the last term.

My thinking was to derive a Sum such that $$S_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=2n}^{2n+1}(-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=-\frac{x^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$ and attempt prove uniform convergence of that.

Would this be an appropriate method or am I going the wrong way about this completely?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the convergence using the following [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test#Abel's_uniform_convergence_test).

**Abel's test:** Let the series of functions $\sum f_n$ be uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$. Let the sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ be monotonic for every $x\in [a,b]$ and uniformly bounded on $[a,b]$. Then the series $\sum f_ng_n$ is uniformly convergent.

For your problem, take $f_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ and $g_n(x)=x^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score -1):

This problem isn't quite difficult. First, the series is a power series, with radius of convergence $R=1$, to obtain this you can use Cauchy-Hadamard formula or Ratio Test.Finally you use Abel's Theorem: if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ ($a_n,x\in\mathbb{R}$) has convergence ratio $R$, and the numerical serie $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n R^n$ converges ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (-R)^n$) then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is uniform convergent in $[0,R]$ ($[-R,0]$).

With this at hand: evaluating in $x=1$ we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}$ and this series is convergent -Leibniz Criteria-. In the other case, $x=-1$ we get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and this series is convergent, again by Leibniz Criteria.
I hope it will be ok for you.

Comment: We didn't cover Abel's Theorem, which could explain why I'm having some trouble with this question. But this kinda makes sense, I was trying to make use of Leibnize Alternating Series Theorem initially until when I thought I had a $M_k$ that could use it.

Comment: Just a curiosity, what if that is a constant c in the power series such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-c)^n$? and is the convergence ratio is 1? Why are we then substituting values of x?

Comment: Also, sorry, but how did $(-1)^n(-1)^{2n+1}$ change into $(-1)^{n-1}$? Wouldn't it be $(-1)^{3n+1}?